# Set JavaCard ATR to be the same as another card from different vendor

Tags: javacard

I am replacing old non JavaCard with JavaCard.  Would it be possible to also change the ATR of my JavaCard to be the same as my legacy card ? From what I read, ATR defines card communication parameters and since each chip has its own properties, does this mean this is not possible ?

Comment: Although I never tried this myself I think this is possible. It also depends on a vendor. You probably should contact it via email and ask. Take [this forum thread](https://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?t=1195) as a reference

Comment: With JavaCard you can change the Historical Bytes. However the initial part is hardware/manufacturer dependent.

Comment: Could you tell me if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29457642/589259) solves your problem? You can only set the historical bytes though; it would not make sense if you could change the card characteristics from an Applet; JavaCard is still a relatively high level runtime / API.

Comment: I contacted the supplier of the card. The required ATR change affects the baud rate transfer of the card (TA1 and TC1 property of the ATR) which fortunately supported by the javacard. The supplier sent document and script (I had to sign NDA) to perform such ATR change. For anyone who may face similar problem, I think the best thing to do is to parse the ATR, send the details to supplier of the card to check if it is supported by the card. Many thanks for all the comments (Sergei, Maarten,Jianza), every bit of the comments helped.